# qmake processes my pro-file three times instead of one

Tags: qt, qmake, vcproj

This is entire `pro` file:

```
message("This message should appeare only once!!!")
CONFIG += qt
SOURCES += src/main.cpp
```

I invoke `qmake` in the following way:

```
set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2008
set QTDIR=c:\Qt\4.8.4_vs2008\

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
call "%QTDIR%\bin\qmake.exe" -tp vc Server.pro
```

And I get following output:

> Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools.
>
> Project MESSAGE: This message should be appeared only once!!!
>
> Project MESSAGE: This message should be appeared only once!!!
>
> Project MESSAGE: This message should be appeared only once!!!

Why did the message print THREE times?

Answer (score 13):

Actually, the condition "build_pass" is always true except the first time qmake parses your .pro file, so the following works:

```
!build_pass:message("This message should appear only once")
```

I made a helper function, which works fine in my project:

```
defineTest(print) {
  !build_pass:message($$1)
}

print("This message should appear only once")
```

Answer (score 10):

Because by default, `qmake` will create 3 makefiles: `Makefile`, `Makefile.debug`, and `Makefile.release`. This is because the default config is to build the project in debug and release modes. If you add `CONFIG -= debug_and_release` to your `.pro` file, you should only see the message once. You can find more info [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html) and [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your .pro file

```
CONFIG -= debug_and_release debug_and_release_target
```

qmake will generate only one Makefile with it and .pro file will be evaluated only once.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this :

```
Release:message("This message should appeare only once!!!")
```

it will run once if you are in relase mode, for debug change to `Debug:...`