# QMake runs code twice with subdirs project, regardless of !build_pass condition

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

Using `Qt 5.12`. I have been trying to make some QMake commands to run only once (instead of three times). I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19119104/4622991), where they make use of the `!build_pass` condition. So I set up my working directory as follows:

```
│   subdirs_test.pro
│
└───test
        test.pro
```

The `test/test.pro` file only contains:

```
!build_pass:message("This message should appear only once")
```

And the `subdirs_test.pro` contains:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS = \
test

test.subdir = $$PWD/test
```

If I run:

```
cd test
qmake -tp vc test.pro
```

Well enough it prints:

```
Project MESSAGE: This message should appear only once
```

But if I run the `subdirs` project:

```
cd ..
qmake -r -tp vc subsdirs_test.pro
```

It prints the message **twice**:

```
Project MESSAGE: This message should appear only once
Project MESSAGE: This message should appear only once
```

Is there a way to make *QMake* just run it **once**?

Comment: Could you try?
!build_pass:CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    message("Hello from build_pass during debug")
}

Comment: The thing is that message needs to be ran once, no matter if one selects debug or release build. In what you propose it would indeed only run once in the debug pass. But in a CI scenario, where we only do the release pass, then it would not be ran.

Answer (score 0):

```
defineReplace(commonFunctionality) {
    message("commonFunctionality")
}

build_pass {
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        message("Debug")
        $$commonFunctionality();
    }
    CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
        message("Release")
        $$commonFunctionality();
    }
}


$ qmake -r -tp vc subdirs_test.pro
Project MESSAGE: Release
Project MESSAGE: commonFunctionality
Project MESSAGE: Debug
Project MESSAGE: commonFunctionality

$ qmake -r -tp vc test.pro
Project MESSAGE: Release
Project MESSAGE: commonFunctionality
Project MESSAGE: Debug
Project MESSAGE: commonFunctionality
```

Comment: So this still prints "commonFunctionality" twice?